# Совместное использование cookie разными приложениями ASPNET.Core

Tags: c#, cookie, микросервисы

Проблема в следующем. У меня есть несколько проектов, связанных между собой (в одном решении). В одном из них происходит авторизация и аутентификация пользователей посредством cookie, с помощью механизма aspnet core. Главный вопрос: как передавать куки между приложениями (пользователь авторизуется один раз в одном приложении и потом считается авторизованным во всех приложениях решения)? В рамках проекта, в котором авторизуется пользователь все хорошо - User.Identity там работает без проблем, но вот каким образом достучаться до кук из других приложений - не понимаю.

Comment: ваши приложеня на одном домене будут задеплоены?

Comment: в обозримом будущем - в локальной сети. домены разные

Comment: окей, на одном DNS имени?

Comment: upd коммент выше)

Comment: то есть вы хотите, чтобы юзер авторизовался на сайте xxx.local, и после этого зашел на yyy.local и там авторизация сработала сама по кукам от xxx.local?

Comment: в идеале да. думал куки грузить в бд, но в json не сериализуется

Comment: я бы гуглил в сторону sso и identityServer

Comment: Возможно поможет данная статья
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-6.0